# How do I setup a second argument for my controller codeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

How do I set up two arguments for my view function in the controller in codeIgniter?
I managed to setup one that takes the `category`. I need to setup a second one that takes the `article alias` in the database but when i go to article i get a 404 error page.

In my view function I passed both of them. The first one `$category_alias` is working  but the second one isn't working. It takes me to 404 page.

This is my controller function

```
public function view($category_alias = NULL, $article_alias = NULL) {
            $data['category'] = $this->categories_model->get_all_categories($category_alias);
            $data['games_by_category'] = $this->categories_model->get_all_articles_by_category($category_alias);
            $data['article_infos'] = $this->categories_model->get_game_infos($article_alias );

                if (empty($data['category'])) {
                        show_404();
                }

                if (isset($article_alias)) {
                    $this->load->view('pages/article_display', $data);
                }
                $data['title'] = $data['category']['category_name']." Games - WalkthroughRemix";

                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/top', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/main_menu', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/breadcrumbs', $data);

                $this->load->view('pages/category_display', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
        }
```

Comment: going to: `/somecontroller/view/{$category_alias}/{$article_alias}/` should not give you a 404. I think you are typing in the url wrong.

Comment: Have you checked that you are getting the data in both parameters? Do a var_dump and exit rather than redirecting the page so you know what data you actually have.

Comment: `var_dump($article_alias)` shows me `$article_alias` the other one displays correctly the category name from my database

Comment: hey you're right but how i make my url not displaying the `view` function

Comment: how to use a new page for the last argument?

Comment: You can't, atleast not easily. If you need a new "page" create a new controller or function.